# Silent 404 with ClassNotFoundException in log

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

Spring tutorial, [part one](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html), question three... (facepalm here)

"Silent 404" means I get a standard 404 from Tomcat with an empty message field.

Excerpt from the Tomcat localhost..log:

```
сен 10, 2013 3:39:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet springapp as unavailable
сен 10, 2013 3:39:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /springapp threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
<stack trace omitted>
```

The class is in `spring-webmvc-4.0.0.M3.jar`, which is placed in `war/WEB-INF/lib/spring`:

```
bash-3.1$ pwd
/c/Users/mkumpan/Projects/Spring testing/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring
bash-3.1$ jar -tf ./spring-webmvc-4.0.0.M3.jar | grep DispatcherServlet
org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.class
...
```

Both the classrefs in my build.xml include that path:

```
<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
</path>

<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Not sure what other info might be relevant.
Hoping for suggested ideas. Dead end again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the spring-webmvc-4.0.0.M3.jar is placed under WEB-INF/lib/spring when the application is *deployed*, tomcat will not be able to find it. It must be placed directly under WEB-INF/lib. (This is true for Tomcat and any Java EE-compliant servlet container.)

Comment: Ah, there's the answer. Tomcat's tomfoolery. Do you know if there's any way to move the jars to subdirectories in lib so tomcat can see them? Currently it's an obfuscated soup of packages.

Comment: No, the jars must be under lib to be visible to the servlet container. What you should probably do for a real project is use some kind of dependency management tool (e.g. Maven) so that your source/project directory is clean. And stop caring for the WAR layout.

Comment: Right, thanks. I guess I could also modify the `deploy` target to dump files from subdirs directly into `lib` on the appserver.

Comment: While deploying you can put these jars in lib dir of tomcat. This way you dont have to add those in war file.

Answer (score 1):

After deployment to app server `spring-webmvc-4.0.0.M3.jar` should be located at `/WEB-INF/lib`, not `/WEB-INF/lib/spring`. So move that jar to `/WEB-INF/lib` or fix ant build to copy it in resulting war

Comment: Vote up for being first. I must accept Nikos' answer though, as he explained WHY this must be so. Kudos regardless.

Answer (score 1):

put your spring jars out of /lib/spring folder -one level up. This will solve your problem.

/c/Users/mkumpan/Projects/Spring testing/war/WEB-INF/lib/ should contain your spring jars.